# Using Input Type Submit Or Button

Tags: html, form-submit, submit-button

I have to use a submit button to submit one of my forms on a website. Is it possible to use the `<button>` element as a submit button? Do I also add the `type="submit"` attribute to the `<button>` element? i.e.

```
<button type="submit">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible!

In fact, the `<button>`'s default behavior is to act as a submit button, so:

```
<button>Go</button>
```

Will do what you expect it to! Buttons are also slightly easier to style, and you can keep them consistent with other types of buttons without adding extra rules or selectors in your CSS.

---

It's worth noting that IE 7 and 6 have some pretty horrible bugs when using `<button value="whatever">Something Else</button>`. If you want lower IE compatibility *and* to use the `value=` attribute, don't use `<button>`

Comment: If you use <button> as a submit you need to add type=submit as well. Otherwise, it is a type=button by default.

Comment: Wrong, [`type=submit` is the default type value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). Also see [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5)

Comment: Have you tried put <button> inside a form element? If not go and have a try so you'll learn a lot.

Comment: [Yes, I have](http://jsfiddle.net/nYgag/1/). Note that the form submits, but Google rejects the request due to same origin policies. See your console and network tab for more details

Comment: It depends then? By the way according to the specs. It needs to declare the type of button anyway "type = submit|button|reset".

Comment: According to the specs, *`submit`: Creates a submit button. **This is the default value.*** Emphasis mine. If you want, we can [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign)

Comment: Alright, my experiences tells me that none of the button tag without "type" always act like "button".

Comment: *"If not go and have a try so you'll learn a lot."*. For an experienced user this sounds exactly as *"I don't know what I'm speaking about"*

Comment: There's something I need to pay a little attention here. According to my experiences - there's a hole in there. This is a prove that with or without type="submit". A <button> also acts like "SUBMIT". http://fiddle.jshell.net/qqQax/ Thanks for a lesson then.

Comment: This does not work in Firefox.  Button type=submit value is not posted at all when clicked.  Works fine in Chrome.

Comment: @Triynko: I cannot reproduce that. Can you [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a different question and include an example?

Answer (score 1):

Following are also 2 types to submit forms

1. `<input type="submit">`
2. The following script

   ```
   <script>
   function SubmitFunction()
   {
    document.getElementById("formid").submit();
   }
   </script>
   <form id="formid" action="abc.php">
   <input type="button" onclick="SubmitFunction()" value="Submit">
   </form>
   ```

Answer (score -1):

**yes** 
    You can use but I have heard that If you use the `<button>` element in an HTML form, 
    different browsers may submit different values. Use `<input>` to create buttons in an HTML form.

Comment: You've heard? Heard where?

Comment: OK, so some information from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button): "IE7 has a bug where when submitting a form with <button... value="foo">Click me</button>, the POST data sent will result in myButton=Click me instead of myButton=foo. IE6 has an even worse bug where submitting a form through a button will submit ALL buttons of the form, with the same bug as IE7. This bug has been fixed in IE8". So, to be specific - if you want IE7 compatibility, and want the button to pass a value, don't use it.

Comment: FYI - you should "check it", as it's your answer!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp 
Read this link, Hope this satisfies u

Comment: Firefox does not submit the button's value at all.  Same exact page works fine in Chrome and submits the buttons value when clicked.  Standards my ass.